# i have installed vlc media player but audio is playing video screen is not showing in desktop

Tags: drivers

i have installed VLC media player but when video is clicked in only audio is played.
no such VLC media player is shown  in desktop only audio is hearing in it

Comment: What happens when you execute vlc via terminal? `vlc /path/to/movie`

Comment: The video is most likely disabled. Just go to the "video menu"->"Video Track"->"Track 1"

Comment: can you tell me what are your computer's specs and what resolution is this video?